# How to handle first run and splashes in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, caliburn.micro

I have spent a bit of time rummaging through Stack Overflow to find out how to deterministically close an application based on an action. Most if not all answers say you can't or shouldn't do it. If this is so I would like to phrase my question differently and see how people are handling two issues I am having trouble with.

Just to let you guys know I am using Caliburn.Micro for this project.

Ok so the flow of my app can be broken down into two parts, the initial flow and the standard flow, these are as follows

Splash -> Welcome -> CreateAccount -> MainHub (all other functionality branches from here)

Splash -> MainHub (all other functionality branches from here)

Based on this flow, the feedback from my better (beta) testers is that they expect to exit the app on pressing the back button on the hub, which they see as the entry point. Currently as per navigation they go all the way back to the splash.

I see other apps have this functionality, but without forcing the application to close (Which I read is a no no) how are they achieving this desired functionality.

NOTE: I do not want to put in an exit button as I believe it goes against the natural flow of a WP7 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you **cannot** add a exit button. The only way to exit a application is to crash it, which **will not** be approved for marketplace certification.

As for your problem, you simply have to remove views from the navigation stack upon completion of a known navigation.

For this, use [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx).

You can access the NavigationService from anywhere, using this snippet:

```
(App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).RemoveBackEntry()
```

Comment: Good advice but I would prefer to do it in the viewmodel if I cannot find another way to do it via caliburn.micro I will do it this way

Comment: Cheers for the update, I have to disagree though, I find it a very intuitive framework to use.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding EULA / Login screens (and Splash) - don't make them into pages. If you instead make them Popup or Dialog controls you can show or hide them at any time (on first navigation; when the user hits a "protected" part of the app; after a time-out; etc.) and they don't consume a slot in the backstack.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx

Comment: Good advice, I will change that, it solves part of my problem.

Comment: A separate page can workout as well, if you use NavigationService.GoBack() after approval/denial. It depends on the navigation flow of the app.